# Jquery delegate not working when setting variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, delegates

I am using ajax loading for page navigation and am using delegate for the various click events required for each function etc

The problem I am having is activating a slideshow on the home page due to the way the slider is activated.

The following is what I have and obviously the `load` does not work as I expected it too...

```
$('#Content').delegate('#Home','load',function(){

swiper = new Swiper('#swiper', {
        mode:'horizontal',
        speed:900 , 
        loop:true,
    });

});
```

Is there a way I can get around this without implementing an if/switch statement within my navigation coding, as I would rather keep this separate.

i have also tried:

```
$(document/body).delegate('#Content','change',function(){....
```

any problems on here I have found are all related to standard problems with delegate like click events not working etc.

Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ? As of 1.7 `.on()` should be used http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: aaahhh I thought it was the other way around!!! i'm using 1.9.1.

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#content', function() { ... })`

Comment: @adeneo Nah didn't work...

Comment: I have since read that the load event wont bubble  so this could be part of the problem?!

Comment: `$(document).on('load','#home', function(event){ alert('loaded'); });`

Comment: That's why I used the change event, does that work, if so the issue is with the load event not the event handler

Comment: Also, not all elements have a load event, and then there is caching etc. What is `#home`

Comment: @adeneo #Home is a section that is loaded directly into #Content. Neither change on #Content nor load on #Home are working... Think i might just have to go with the If statement in the nav code! Unless, maybe if i try the load on the images within the swiper slider?? Thanks